# Get corrupted encoded data while converting byte array to base64 string in android

Tags: java, android, base64

I am developing an android application in my application I wanted to convert byte array of image to base64 string .But when I am converting i get corrupted result.

**This is my AsyncTask**

```
 public class Test1 extends AsyncTask<Void, byte[], String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            myClient2 = new Socket("192.168.1.1", 6666);

            System.out.println("a:" + myClient2);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject1.put("cmd", "request_download_file");
                jsonObject1.put("file_name", filename1);
                jsonObject1.put("verification", "CVS");


                System.out.println("File name========" + filename1);

                System.out.println("b111111111111111" + jsonObject1);
                myClient2.setKeepAlive(true);
                System.out.println(myClient2.getLocalAddress() + " " + myClient2.getLocalSocketAddress() + " " + myClient2.getKeepAlive());
                System.out.println(myClient2.getKeepAlive());
                try {

                    DataInputStream dis1 = new DataInputStream(myClient2.getInputStream());

                    //reads file length from datainputstream
                    DataOutputStream dos1 = new DataOutputStream(myClient2.getOutputStream());
                    jsonReader1 = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(dis1));//, "UTF-8"));

                    InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(dis1);

                    writer1 = new OutputStreamWriter(dos1);//, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                    writer1.write(jsonObject1.toString());
                    System.out.println("c");
                    writer1.flush();

                    BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(myClient2.getInputStream());
                    Log.e("input", "input" + input);

                    byte[] data = new byte[1024];

                    BufferedReader brdr = new BufferedReader(inputReader, 300);

                    boolean status = false;


                    int countPackets = 0;

                    while (!status) {

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // or 4096, or more

                        int bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                        int availableBytes = input.available();


                        str2 = str2.append(bytesRead);

                        ImageDataArray = concat(ImageDataArray, buffer);

                        countPackets = countPackets + buffer.length;

                        System.out.println(ImageDataArray.length);




                        System.out.println(countPackets);

                        System.out.println("get" + ImageDataArray);


                        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                                .format(new Date());


                        System.out.println("check--" + timeStamp + "--");


                        if (input.available() != 0) {
                            System.out.println("String:" + str1.toString());
                        } else break;
                    }

                    System.out.println("--------------------out of while ------------------");

                    System.out.println("filename===========" + filename1);
                    // String filename = String.format("%s%s", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile(), "/SteelmanPro/1020/images/image34" + ".jpg");

                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile().toString(), "/SteelmanPro/1020/images/image");



                    if (!file.exists()) {

                        file.mkdirs();
                        System.out.println("File Created++++++++++++++++++");

                    }


                    int position = - 1;

                    for (int i = 0; i < ImageDataArray.length - 2; i++) {
                        if (ImageDataArray[i] == (byte) 0xff && ImageDataArray[i + 1] == (byte) 0xdf) {
                            position = i;
                            Log.e("position", "position." + position);

                            break;
                        }
                    }


                    write(ImageDataArray,file.toString() +filename1);


                    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString((byte[])ImageDataArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                   Log.i("Base64=========",encodedImage.toString());


                    int a = data.length;

                    Log.e("data.length", "data.length" + a);



                    System.out.println("String:" + str1.toString());
                    normalLoginResponse = hexChars;


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("send JSON error");
            }
            System.out.println("d");
            System.out.println("e");
            System.out.println("f");
            System.out.println("g");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("creation exception1");

        }

        return normalLoginResponse;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

}
```

**Logcat**

```
Base64=========: eyJjbWQiOiJyZXNwb25zZV9kb3dubG9hZF9maWxlIiwicmVzdWx0Ijoic3VjY2VzcyIsImZpbGVf
                                                             c2l6ZSI6IjQwMzgzMyJ9DQoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                                                             AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                                                             AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                                                             AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                                                             AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                                                             AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                                                             AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                                                             AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                                                             AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                                                             AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                                                             AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                                                             AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                                                             AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                                                             AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                                                             AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                                                             AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                                                             AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/Y
                                                             /+ERHUV4aWYAAE1NACoAAAAIAAwBAAADAAAAAQQAAAABAQADAAAAAQMAAAABAgADAAAAAwAAAJ4B
                                                             BgADAAAAAQACAAABEgADAAAAAQABAAABFQADAAAAAQADAAABGgAFAAAAAQAAAKQBGwAFAAAAAQAA
                                                             AKwBKAADAAAAAQACAAABMQACAAAAHAAAALQBMgACAAAAFAAAANCHaQAEAAAAAQAAAOQAAAEcAAgA
                                                             CAAIAAr8gAAAJxAACvyAAAAnEEFkb2JlIFBob3Rvc2hvcCBDUzUgV2luZG93cwAyMDE2OjA1OjI1
                                                             IDE4OjE4OjM2AAAEkAAABwAAAAQwMjIxoAEAAwAAAAH//wAAoAIABAAAAAEAAAXcoAMABAAAAAEA
                                                             AARlAAAAAAAAAAYBAwADAAAAAQAGAAABGgAFAAAAAQAAAWoBGwAFAAAAAQAAAXIBKAADAAAAAQAC
                                                             AAACAQAEAAAAAQAAAXoCAgAEAAAAAQAAD5sAAAAAAAAASAAAAAEAAABIAAAAAf/Y/+0ADEFkb2Jl
                                                             X0NNAAL/7gAOQWRvYmUAZIAAAAAB/9sAhAAMCAgICQgMCQkMEQsKCxEVDwwMDxUYExMVExMYEQwM
                                                             DAwMDBEMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMAQ0LCw0ODRAODhAUDg4OFBQODg4OFBEM
                                                             DAwMDBERDAwMDAwMEQwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAz/wAARCAB4AKADASIAAhEB
                                                             AxEB/90ABAAK/8QBPwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAwABAgQFBgcICQoLAQABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAA
                                                             AAABAAIDBAUGBwgJCgsQAAEEAQMCBAIFBwYIBQMMMwEAAhEDBCESMQVBUWETInGBMgYUkaGxQiMk
                                                             FVLBYjM0coLRQwclklPw4fFjczUWorKDJkSTVGRFwqN0NhfSVeJl8rOEw9N14/NGJ5SkhbSVxNTk
                                                             9KW1xdXl9VZmdoaWprbG1ub2N0dXZ3eHl6e3x9fn9xEAAgIBAgQEAwQFBgcHBgU1AQACEQMhMRIE
                                                             QVFhcSITBTKBkRShsUIjwVLR8DMkYuFygpJDUxVjczTxJQYWorKDByY1wtJEk1SjF2RFVTZ0ZeLy
                                                             s4TD03Xj80aUpIW0lcTU5PSltcXV5fVWZnaGlqa2xtbm9ic3R1dnd4eXp7fH/9oADAMBAAIRAxEA
                                                             PwDgk8lKE8IKVuKeSmhOAkpcEqQKiApAJKXkp5KQCeElKkpSU4anDUlLap5Kfan2pKWkp5KfaltS
                                                             UtuKUlPtT7UlMEjKntTbUlIyE0Im1NtSU//Q4WE8KQCUIKYwpAJwFIBJTENUg1SAUg1JTENUg1SD
                                                             VMNSUwDU4aiBqkGpKRhifYihik2pzvotLvgJSUh2JbFYOPY36Tdv9Ytb/wBW5qhDCYD2EjmHsP5H
                                                             I0pFtS2ooDXGGlrj4Ag/9SU5rI5BQUg2pbUbamLUlIdqYtRS1MWpKf/R4kJ0wCkgpQCkAmAKkAUl
                                                             MgFIBMNFJ1dwg2OFFEAuI/nXa/RE/QYipk1smAJJ7DlTAG4s1e8c1sgkf13H9HX/AGnKo7qFMEe/
                                                             Yf8AB1+0n/jr3f8AUVKDuqWhuylrKGDhrBP/AEne3/oJKbd1jqiXlllVQ72sDwD/AMbj2H/z0gDK
                                                             e+0WU5WM5kQKLCWj+t+l9F27+0qF2QbtLi+wDUAkxPkPooYHtJLRtJ0JS+inUbj9Sex5LfWfINPp
                                                             uDmdw9rxU5/t+jYr+E7Ma1wdVlW2NYC4VU7pLfZvt/Oa1v8AIrsXNhrR7toA117Lr8DH/wCbHQB1
                                                             7Ol/VM4FvSMWwktqaRrn21O/wux36H/RIhDiVW4VLTYWVX7eA6Zn930v3lpUZzrW1hgZQyzRrQAD
                                                             v4Nbmw1u9jvzFz2U8jIeQ42PLjve8kuJIHuc785yYZB+y2Vk7fex7YPxrf8A+iv8xJLvO6X1fLv/
                                                             AEtWFdWD7LLvYf8AwL6P9tqpWZzMK44uZi24VrPpMaQ9on84bfT3Md/pK/UWl0rqjsjFY60EXCGP
                                                             EH3GPbY3+u36av5XQczrLGV3Y/pMrMsvtOxwB+kxjYfa5j/3PTQA7Ktxce+rIe0UZDXBxAJJ+iJ1
                                                             e9j9r2tYim0N0llx8WtLRH9f2+5bLPq30HpbYy8gNd3Y2GE/+fst/wDnJzk/VatjmNx9zSCC7Y4u
                                                             /s22u3sd/KRrxVY7OJuYeJHkUiFXry6bMxuO1r2kn2F4gOj3R/m/yUcnUoEKf//S44VlTFSstoKM
                                                             zGsdu9Ot1prY6xzWDcQxn85Y79ytn59j/Ykpp+mGgudo0ckqDb6QfoFw+MIOS592TW6u0WVtjdWG
                                                             uaGbmhz5dZHqWMe70fb9P0/Ur/QojWHsISGotR00bD8prqHspa2i0j2PAEgj+UdzljZH24kuvD3/
                                                             AMrkfe1araUZlUI0i3n2WsJh2h80YMrdEHnhbjsSi0fpa2v/AKwBP3qI6TgkAeloOBudA+HuSpTj
                                                             CkTEx4k/3InpVBoDtdvGq2WdJwhxWR/bd/5JWsL6sDqLzXjUPsA+m42ObW3/AIywu2f2fppUprfU
                                                             /oWL1DOszc0x0jpjfWzHWaMe8TZVj/yqtrfWv/4P9H/hU/WbOs/Wfq
```

if anyone know this please help me

Comment: ImageDataArray - is it your byte[] ?

Comment: Then what is corrupted?

Comment: You should tell what the server is sending. And what you read from the socket. Did you compare the amount of bytes sent with the amount of bytes received? Figures please.

Comment: `.encodeToString((byte[])ImageDataArray` Time to tell the type of your array. That cast looks bad.

Comment: `write(ImageDataArray,file.toString() +filename1);` What should that do? Where is write() defined? If it creates a file then is it a valid file? You mis a / here i think.

Comment: @greenapps  When I receive data I get extra 2KB of data. eg: suppose I send 677KB image , then at receiver side it will be 679KB. So I think the extra data is AAAA.. printed in the logcat.

Comment: You have not given all the info i asked for. And you will not have received extra A's as an A will not be an A anymore when base64 encoded. Now try again. And exact figures! Every byte counts. Three sizes please.

Comment: So i wonder why you focus on the base64 encoding going wrong. Probably it does not and has nothing to do with it. You should focus on receiving an equal amount of bytes as have been sent. Please elaborate what is sent. You are talking about an image but it will be a file i think.

Answer (score 0):

You are using BufferedReader to receive the bytes of an image file.

That will not work as you have seen as a reader is for text data.

So do away with it.